# Guarantee data sent to SQL Server gets there unmanipulated

Tags: c++, sql-server-2008-r2

We are working on a security-critical software, and we have the constraint that we need to guarantee that data we want to store on our server can not be manipulated on the way between client and server.

What´s the correct way to guarantee that? Does SQL Server 2008 R2 have methods to do that? I found something like "message authentication code", but I couldn't find a good explanation.

Our only idea would be to calculate an [MD5](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MD5) checksum on client and server and sending back feedback to the client to check whether the data got there unmanipulated or not. Would that be thinkable? Is there a better way?

The client is a C++ client that runs on Windows 7.

Comment: Perhaps [securing the connection](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189067(v=sql.105).aspx) between the server and the client may do what you desire.

Comment: Can you define "client"?

Comment: By securing the connection i still dont know for sure whether the data got manipulated or not